# Javascript redirect for Internet Explorer browser version user agent?

Tags: javascript, redirect, user-agent

I found out that my javascript-intensive web site doesn't work reliably (or at all) in IE9.

It works, (usually, but not always) with the compatibility mode meta tag in the header, but I just want to build a page that I know will work well in IE9 and then have the usual page redirect to it when IE9 is detected. The usual page is fine in IE 7 and 8 (and every other browser I've tried it on).

Can anyone give me some javascript that will do that? Thank you!

Here's my usual page:

http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/test/

Comment: Your site gets JavaScript errors in Chrome.  You might want to check into that.

Comment: Found this, but I think I prefer browser functionality detection in retrospect. See: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14835682/2140998

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use [IE Conditionals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Note:** IE10 and beyond have [removed support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh801214(v=vs.85).aspx) for this feature. For modern browsers the widely accepted way of conditionally displaying content for compatibility purposes is using [feature detection](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/detection/#feature-detection). [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) is a popular library built for handling feature detection.

For example:

```
<!--[if IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://www.ie9version.com";
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

Examples from the conditional site:

```
<!--[if IE]><p>You are using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]-->
<![if !IE]><p>You are not using Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]>

<!--[if IE 7]><p>Welcome to Internet Explorer 7!</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if !(IE 7)]><p>You are not using version 7.</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if gte IE 7]><p>You are using IE 7 or greater.</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if (IE 5)]><p>You are using IE 5 (any version).</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 5.5)&(lt IE 7)]><p>You are using IE 5.5 or IE 6.</p><![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 5.5]><p>Please upgrade your version of Internet Explorer.</p><![endif]-->

<!--[if true]>You are using an <em>uplevel</em> browser.<![endif]-->
<![if false]>You are using a <em>downlevel</em> browser.<![endif]>

<!--[if true]><![if IE 7]><p>This nested comment is displayed in IE 7.</p><![endif]><![endif]-->
```

Comment: And perhaps a meta redirect inside a `<noscript>` (or just the meta redirect; I don't know which is more reliable)

Comment: Okay, that looks nice and simple--if I just want to redirect for IE, all versions, then I'd have <![if IE ]> ? Thanks!

Comment: Yep! I'll throw some more examples from the page in the answer.

Comment: Hmmm... It's redirecting in all browsers, not just IE... Here's what I've pasted right below the opening head tag:    <![if IE 8>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.location = "http://ianmartinphotography.com";
</script>
<![endif]>  and here's the page, but it will most likely redirect on ya...http://ianmartinphotography.com/test-site/test/newcurveredirect.html Thanks for your help!

Comment: I just updated the answer. They need to be commented conditional comments.  <!--[if IE 9]><![endif]--> instead of <![if IE 9]><![endif]>.

Comment: @Bengel, can I a redirect for more than one, say, IE 6, IE 7 and IE 8? What would that look like?

Comment: Yep, its flexible. For example if you want to redirect on IE8 or lower it would look like: <!--[if lte IE 8]><![endif]-->

Comment: Just note this is not working for IE 10. If you need a solution for it, check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502040/if-ie-conditionals-not-working

Answer (score -1):

```
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript"> 
<!-- 

  if( navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1 || 
      navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf("msie") > -1 ) { 
    window.open("http://www.pobox.com/~qed/windoze.html", "Windoze",
"dependent=no,titlebar=no,scrollbars=yes" ); 
  } 

// Paul Hsieh 
// qed at pobox dot com 
// --> 
</script>
```

Source: http://www.cexx.org/snicker/nomsie.htm