# How do I block my webpage from opening in Internet Explorer 11?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I found an old solution online for validating what browser a user is using, and have it display a message: https://github.com/bml3i/browser-validator-js

Unfortunately, the "msie" portion of the code doesn't seem to be working with IE 11. Is there a simple solution I can use in order to display a message to IE 11 users that the webpage will not display correctly on their browser?

Thank you! (◕‿◕✿)

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cssuseragent

Comment: checkout this answer which includes IE 11 https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/1309377 Once you detect its IE you can display whatever you want

Comment: How do I implement this into the main Layout.cshtml page?

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options

1. [Bowser](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser) - Will detect browser, then you can run whatever JS you
   want (good for triggering something like a modal)
2. [Outdated browser](http://outdatedbrowser.com/en) - Probably more than what you're looking for, but may be a good option
3. [CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41169344/727717) - this works for IE 10 & 11

   ```
       @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {  
           /* Put your IE-only styles here. Works for IE 10 & IE 11*/
       }
   ```