# How to target all IE browsers (except Microsoft Edge ) in <style>

Tags: html, css, browser

I need to target all IE browser in  ....  inside html file.

I see on internet

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

But how to target this inside  ?

What i need ?

```
     <!-- Internet Explorer ONLY
    .actionbar-container {
        left: 0!important;
       }
    <!-- Internet Explorer ONLY
```

Comment: Targeting for browsers (as opposed to feature support) is generally bad practice. What's the need here?

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502040/if-ie-conditionals-not-working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19502040/if-ie-conditionals-not-working)

Answer (score 1):

Check those links I think they might be helpful:

https://www.ryadel.com/en/css3-media-query-target-only-ie-ie6-ie11-firefox-chrome-safari-edge/

https://keithclark.co.uk/articles/moving-ie-specific-css-into-media-blocks/media-tests/

You can try creating a style file specifically to target Internet Explorer and it's different versions and use media query like for example :

```
@media screen and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution: +72dpi) {
    // IE9+ CSS
    .ie9up { 
        property: value; 
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont' understand/............... i need only how to target class without media qury without extrernal file.............

Comment: .ie6 { _property: value; } Where to set my class actionbar-container ?!!?

Comment: Not sure but I don't think that it possible to target the class to work only on Internet Explorer without media query.

Comment: Ok with media query where to set my class . actionbar-container  ?

Comment: Replace the the current with yours like this for example: @media screen and (min-width:0\0) and (min-resolution: +72dpi) {
    // IE9+ CSS
  .actionbar-container {
        left: 0!important;
       }
}

Comment: Write me where to set . actionbar-container  and media query and all..... I don't know\