# Browser compatibility check in MVC app.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am developing MVC application.
some jquery not work at all in IE 8 browser.
so I don't want to run that app. on IE 8 and lesser versions.
If user running it on IE 8 or lesser version , I dont want to run application on that browser.
What should I do ?

Comment: See this post and add logic to handle it as you see fit

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574842/best-way-to-check-for-ie-less-than-9-in-javascript-without-library

Comment: Rather than browser detection, you should probably be using feature detection using a library such as modernizr instead.