# IE8 does not apply the style even when its Developer Tools shows it

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, pseudo-element

I wonder if anyone has encountered this and what they did to fix it.
IE, is not applying a style for a class I added at runtime (jQuery). The weird thing is that the Developer Tools is showing it should be applied. See picture below.

The "fa-bars" element has a parent with "blue" class. In this case, I added the "blue" class within $(document).ready(). If I add the "blue" class on the HTML markup (instead of doing it at run-time), it applies the style correctly. But that is not what I want to do.

I only have this problem on IE (I use IE8), but Chrome and FF both render the page as I expect (correctly). Any ideas on how to solve this?

It appears to be a problem only when rendering pseudo content (eg, FontAwesome). If I replace the  element with plain text, it works.

[image]

**ADDED:**

Here's my full HTML with links to CDNs for FontAwesome and jQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
        <title>Test</title>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.nav-toc').addClass('blue');
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .fa {font-size: 1.5em;}
            .nav-toc {color: red;}
            .blue {color: blue;}
        </style>
    </head>

    <body class="pson-green">
        <div id="master-body">
            <!-- Top banner (Menu) -->
            <div id="master-header">
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <div id="nav-grp-toc" class="nav-container">
                        <div class="nav-btn nav-toc" title="Contents Menu"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i></div>
                    </div><div id="nav-grp-help" class="nav-container">
                        <div class="nav-btn nav-help" title="Help"><i class="fa fa-question"></i></div>
                    </div><div id="nav-grp-counters" class="nav-container">
                        <div id="page-counter" class="nav-page counter-panel">
                            <div id="current-page" class="current-count" title="Current page number"></div>
                            <div id="total-pages" class="max-count" title="Total number of pages"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="question-counter" class="nav-quiz counter-panel">
                            <div id="current-question" class="current-count" class="Current question number"></div>
                            <div id="total-questions" class="max-count" title="Total number of questions"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div><div id="nav-grp-steppers" class="nav-container">
                        <div class="nav-btn nav-page nav-prev" title="Back"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></div>
                        <div class="nav-btn nav-page nav-next" title="Next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
                    </div><div id="nav-grp-exit" class="nav-container">
                        <div class="nav-btn nav-page nav-exit" title="Exit Course"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="dimmer-for-header" class="dimmer"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>   
</html>
```

Comment: @crush, what do you mean?

Comment: He means post your code

Comment: Ok, "content" was too general. But thanks for clarifying

Comment: Got a feeling your jQuery isn't even running.  Check your script debugger/console and see if there's something like `$ is undefined`

Comment: @Deryck, it is running on mine, using this code I posted (which I copied and pasted and re-tested).

Comment: It may be a delay at your end in getting jquery from the CDN, IMHO. It should work with a local jquery copy.

Comment: it does work with local.  it works perfectly actually but I'm in linux running chrome lol.  Even though I can't give you the cause, you could always use `.removeClass('nav-toc').addClass('blue');`

Comment: @Deryck, It also does not work. But thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Only other thing (besides avoiding IE 8 at all costs) might be putting your scripts at the end of your `<body>` tag and see if it changes it.

Comment: @Deryck, that does not work either. That's how my actual work is. The function that adds the class is in a script tag below the page (as I call the function after load. I simply changed it here for simplicity. I now officially want to bury IE8 alive.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46478/discussion-between-deryck-and-frank-fajardo)

Comment: Hi Deryck, thanks for the offer to chat. I've decided to go with the solution I posted below... for now at least :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I may have found an answer. It appears from my searches for similar posts, the problem is with IE's handling of pseudo elements. Unfortunately, I number of answers/suggestions on these posts don't appear to work in my case, except for this [SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809351/ie8-css-font-face-fonts-only-working-for-before-content-on-over-and-sometimes). Basically, it suggests forcing IE to redraw the pseudo element by temporarily adding to the DOM a style tag which removes all pseudo content, and then removing that style tag immediately afterwards. It seems to work, when combined with a check for IE8 based on this [SO item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574842/best-way-to-check-for-ie-less-than-9-in-javascript-without-library). I added this to my script:

```
var ie = (function () {
    var undef,
    v = 3,
    div = document.createElement('div'),
    all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');
    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
                        all[0]
                        );
   return v > 4 ? v : undef;
 } ());

 function redrawPseudos() {
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style');
    style.type = 'text/css';
    style.styleSheet.cssText = ':before,:after{content:none !important;}';
    head.appendChild(style);
    setTimeout(function () {
        head.removeChild(style);
    }, 0);
 }
```

So when I have to add/remove a class, which I expect to impact the styling of a pseudo element, I have to do this:

```
 $('.class1').addClass('newclass');   
 if (ie === 8) {
    redrawPseudos();
 }
```

It is probably an expensive way of doing it. But I only have less than a dozen of pseudo elements.

**ADDED:**

You can improve this by passing a selector to redrawPseudos() and including it to the style. This will limit the redraw to the elements identified by your selector.

```
function redrawPseudos(sel) {
    ...
    style.styleSheet.cssText = sel + ':before, ' + sel + ':after, ' + sel + ' *:before, ' + sel + ' *:after ' + '{content:none !important;}';
    ...
}
```