# Check if IE8 with pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I used to check it this way:

```
$.browser.msie && $.browser.version == 8
```

But it seems that `$.browser` has been removed from the later versinos of jQuery,

So,

How can I check that with just pure javascript?

I tried:

`isIE8: navigator.appVersion.indexOf("MSIE 8") > 0`

Wich seems to Do it, but it doesn't look that good and actually looks like it have many flaws...

Any better aproach?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574842/best-way-to-check-for-ie-less-than-9-in-javascript-without-library

Comment: Why do you think it doesn't look good and has flaws?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965091/1420197

Comment: What specifically do you need to know if it's IE8 for? The most secure way is to use feature detection rather than browser detection, so you're checking if the specific features/functions you want actually exist, and using workarounds if they don't.

Comment: "actually looks like it have many flaws" — that sums up browser detection.

Comment: For all of you suggesting the older questions with answers relying on conditional comments, keep in mind that IE11 does *not* support conditional comments even in IE5-9 mode. Can be annoying while debugging.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist because I apply a filter instead of a background-size

Comment: @putvande yes, well... parsing user agent and matching with a string.. is, at least, not elegant.. is it?

Comment: Best solution IMHO:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965203/134120

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is longer than the one-liner you probably want, but safer than parsing the UA string, because it's based on actual behaviour (IE conditional comments): https://gist.github.com/paulirish/357741

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the `SVG` tag is supported. `SVG` was not supported in IE8 -> http://caniuse.com/#search=svg To the opposit, the `DATA` tag was introduced in IE8 -> http://caniuse.com/#search=data

So :

```
if (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('msie') != -1) {
   if (!document.createElement('SVG').getAttributeNS) {
       if (document.createElement('DATA').getAttributeNS) {
           //the browser is defently IE8
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: omit if(document.createElement('DATA').getAttributeNS ... if you want to check <= IE8