# how to detect msie less than 10?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There might be a lot of question and answers but I couldn't find it really the best, fastest and easiest way to detect the internet explorer version of lower than 10.

So, how can I detect internet explorer less than 10?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10964966/2137653

Comment: You don't; rather, you detect which browser features you can use or not.

Comment: @kamilkp I need only js solution but your provided answer is with html too.

Comment: You should detect browser features. You can use libraries like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/)

Comment: This should do:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574842/best-way-to-check-for-ie-less-than-9-in-javascript-without-library

Comment: I need to detect less than 10 of ie

Comment: @Sudhir that also I visited already but detect only less than 9. I tried that too but not worked...

Comment: @NavinRauniyar Why exactly do you need to detect this?

Comment: My application not run below 10.

Comment: @NavinRauniyar [A bullet proof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/efy5bay1%28v=VS.94%29.aspx) way to detect any IE version...

Comment: @downvoter please give me the answer....

Comment: @Teemu I can't see the script there to detect

Comment: Hmm... [See also](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x7cbaet3%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) at the bottom of the linked MSDN article...

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution as fast, and as short as the solution listed below.

```
var IElt10=0/*@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version<10)1@end@*/;
```

The solution above will set the value of the variable IElt10 to 0 (which evaluates as false in an if-statement) if the browser is greater than 10, and 1 (which evaluates as true in an if-statement) if the browser is less than 10. This will allow you use the above code to do something such as:

```
var IElt10=0/*@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version<10)1@end@*/;
if (IElt10){
    alert("You are using a version of internet explorer less than 10");
} else {
    alert("You're not using a version of internet explorer less than 10");
}
```

It works based on [conditional comments](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_comment). Because conditional comments are still comments, most (if not all) minifiers won't detect that a conditional comment is important and discard it with the rest of the comments. An easy way to overcome this is by simply placing the value of IElt10 in something like alert as shown below:

## Source Code:

```
var IElt10=alert(0/*@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version<10)1@end@*/);
if (IElt10){
    alert("You are using a version of internet explorer less than 10");
} else {
    alert("You're not using a version of internet explorer less than 10");
}
```

Then, you can minify your code. And, in the minified code, find the alert, and replace the whole alert statement (i.e. the entire alert(0)) with the original expression. For example:

## Minified Before:

```
alert(0)?alert("You are using a version of internet explorer less than 10"):alert("You're not using a version of internet explorer less than 10")
```

Now, replace that `alert(0)` with `0/@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version<10)1@end@/` as shown below.

## Minified After:

```
0/*@cc_on@if(@_jscript_version<10)1@end@*/?alert("You are using a version of internet explorer less than 10"):alert("You're not using a version of internet explorer less than 10")
```

And, wala:  you outsmarted the minifier, so now you have working, minified code.

Answer (score -1):

You could test for the user agent string in the browser, but these days that is discouraged in opposition to detecting specific features that your web app requires. Check out frameworks like [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/) which make that easier for you. If you really want to go for detecting IE <10, there is "MSIE" in the UA string followed by a version, e.g. "MSIE 9.0"

Comment: `userAgent` is vulnerable to spoofing by the user or misrepresentation by the browser itself

Comment: that only detects 9 only but I need less than 10.

Comment: you do realise you can parseInt(value) < 10