# Problems with Richefaces default editor on IE9 or edge

Tags: jsf, tinymce, internet-explorer-9, richfaces

I had a problem with default editor (TinyMCE) of Richfaces version 3.3.1.GA when the user is using Internet Explorer 9. I've read many people here and on the Internet who prefer to use X-UA-Compatible metadata to downgrade IE version, but, I dislike it. I always prefer to use the edge version because I'm using CSS 3 as well.
Another solution was a upgrade of RichFaces however I've not considered the possibility for the sake that my application is a pretty legacy.

Answer (score 0):

Then I started unzipping the RichFacesUI jar and changing the file **META-INF/resources-config.xml** from:

```
 <resource>
   <name>scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js</name>
   <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js</path>
   <renderer class="org.ajax4jsf.resource.ScriptRenderer"/>
 </resource>
```

to:

```
 <resource>
   <name>scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce.js</name>
   <path>org/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/tiny_mce/tiny_mce_src.js</path>
   <renderer class="org.ajax4jsf.resource.ScriptRenderer"/>
 </resource>
```

This is to ease the script debugging. That would be pretty hard without it.

First of all these problems are occur because Richfaces uses a specific statement to old IEs therefore I putted the following code to know what version of IE is execution:

```
var ie = (function(){

    var undef,
        v = 3,
        div = document.createElement('div'),
        all = div.getElementsByTagName('i');

    while (
        div.innerHTML = '<!--[if gt IE ' + (++v) + ']><i></i><![endif]-->',
        all[0]
    );

    return v > 4 ? v : undef;

}());
```

PS: This clever code is from [James Padolsey](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/detect-ie-in-js-using-conditional-comments/) and I found it here in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574842/best-way-to-check-for-ie-less-than-9-in-javascript-without-library).

Then I ran my application and where it broke I changed the closest IE if statement as the following examples:

Before it was:

```
if (isIE) {
```

Then it became:

```
if (ie < 9) {
```

And when it was negative statement like:

```
if (!isIE) {
```

Then it became:

```
if (!isIE || ie > 8) {
```

The only difference was in the getXML function which was like:

```
if (!i || !i.createDocument) {
```

Then I changed to:

```
if (!i || !i.createDocument || ie > 8) {
```

[In this Gist](https://gist.github.com/steimntz/89a516793dbce7209c2a/revisions) are all changes that I did. I hope that it helps anyone with this problem.

If you want I putted the jars which I changed on the following links:

- [Richfaces-impl-3.3.1.GA](http://www.filedropper.com/richfaces-impl-331ie9fixga)
- [Richfaces-ui-3.3.1.GA](http://www.filedropper.com/richfaces-ui-331ie9tinymcefixga)

Please, sorry my English mistakes, you are encouraged to re-write and fix this post.